# Slow wifi with D-link DWA-160 A2

Tags: wireless, networking

I recently bought a USB wifi adapter for my new desktop computer. It's a D-link DWA-160 A2. From the start it didn't want to work at all, but after unplugging and then plugging it back in, it seems to work.

However, my browsing is painfully slow. NetworkManager reports the connection to be at around 78-85% signal strength, which seems perfectly acceptable.

Is there anything I can do to make it faster? I'm dual booting with Windows 7, where it seems to work fine, so I'm guessing that the problem occurs because of crappy drivers.

Answer (score 2):

What is the chipset of D-link DWA-160 A2 ? Googling a bit, it seems to be an Atheros chipset. If it happens to be an AR9285, you are using the ath9k driver and might be hitting bug 518818 (on launchpad)

Using latest compat-wireless solved the issue for me, so you can try it:

1) download compat-wireless 2010-09-12.tar.bz2 from http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-2.6/

2) unpack it

3) make

4) sudo make install

This should do the trick (if your problem is the one I suppose of course)